# Google Keep - "Submit"-Button instead of "New-Line" in Textfield - User-friendly?

Tags: android, google, submit, enter-key

Some of you might know "Google Keep", where you can create notes.
Everytime I use this app I'm wondering if this "submit"-design is smart or not. I'm always confused and press the button on the top (red circle), to "create" the note. Unfortunately, this opens a bigger view for my note and doesn't save it.

The "enter/submit"-button on the bottom (red circle) is the way, google finally creates the note. But this button is always supposed to insert a new line in my textfield (whatsapp, gmail, every other app).

Can someone of you explain what the intention behind this "unusual" behaviour is? Or am I the only one who gets tricked by this almost every time ;)

[image: GoogleKeep]

Answer (score 3):

The reason could be because typical use cases for Google Keep might involve more single line, quick notes rather than longer ones. A priority is given to quick notes that can be done in a single step, while longer ones require more steps.

I do admit though that on your phone, it's confusing because the icon on the bottom right button is for new line. It appears differently in mine. This raises the age old issue of android apps behaving differently across various OEMs.

[image: Google Keep on Nexus 4]

Comment: thanks for the picture! It's more clear on your keyboard!